# How to make pytorch 11-output model by combining three sequential models of 4, 3 and 4 shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I'm trying to move my project from Tensorflow to Pytorch to compare the accuracy. The overall data flow is as follows (the number in brackets refers to layer output size):
[image]

Now, in Tensorflow I can use functional API and write three `tf.keras.Sequential`:

```
def single_model(topology):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(topology, activation = relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(topology, activation = relu)])
    return model
input_ANN = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(21,), name="Input")
model1=single_model(4)(input_ANN)
model2=single_model(3)(input_ANN)
model3=single_model(4)(input_ANN)
concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1, name='Concatenate')([model1, model2, model3])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ANN], outputs=[concat])
```

And from this point I have a complete single model to work as with typical single-road ANN. But how to do the same with `Pytorch`? I was trying to do this as follow (21 is input size)

```
# define the model
def single_model(topology):
    model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(21, topology),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(topology, topology),
        nn.ReLU())
    return model
# define the model

model1=single_model(3)
model2=single_model(4)
model3=single_model(3)
model=nn.Sequential(*model1.children(),*model2.children(),*model3.children())
```

But it fails with the error `running_mean should contain 3 elements not 21`. The error is on the lane where I try to generate model prediction in fitting loop:

```
for e in range(epochs):
    train_loss = 0.0
    model.train()     # Optional when not using Model Specific layer
    for data, labels in train_dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        target = model(data) #Here it crash
        loss = MARELoss(target,labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer. Step()
        train_loss += loss. Item()
```

Can you please advise me how to connect the sub-models in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case someone will deal with the same problem, the solution is to subclass Model:

```
class Model(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Model, self).__init__()

    self.d1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(21, 4), nn.Linear(4, 4))
    self.d2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(21, 3), nn.Linear(3, 3))
    self.d3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(21, 4), nn.Linear(4, 4))

  def forward(self, x):
    return torch.cat((self.d1(x), self.d2(x), self.d3(x)), dim=1)
```

And now the instance of model can be created `model = Model()`

Keep in mind that `torch.cat` will not work as expected outside the class definition as in this context it would expect tensor, not sequential as input.